# Symfony Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't44.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have recently made chances to a class Employe this class herit from User,
I've made the chages due to encrypt password :

```
$employe = new Employe();

        $form = $this->createForm(EmployeType::class, $employe);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $employe->setUsername($form->get("email")->getData());
            $employe->getUtilisateur()->setPassword(
              $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                  $employe,
                  $form->get('utilisateur')['password']->getData()
              )
```

This made make me a compile error to fixe, it In my entity I now Extend Employe from User

```
class Employe extends User
```

But know I have the following error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS
> email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS
> enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login
> AS last_login_8, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_9,
> t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_10, t0.roles AS
> roles_11, t0.id AS id_12, t0.nom AS nom_13, t0.prenom AS prenom_14,
> t0.telephone AS telephone_15, t0.fax AS fax_16, t0.is_active AS
> is_active_17, t0.date_first_login AS date_first_login_18, t0.role AS
> role_19, t0.portable_pro AS portable_pro_20, t21.username AS
> username_22, t21.username_canonical AS username_canonical_23,
> t21.email AS email_24, t21.email_canonical AS email_canonical_25,
> t21.enabled AS enabled_26, t21.salt AS salt_27, t21.password AS
> password_28, t21.last_login AS last_login_29, t21.confirmation_token
> AS confirmation_token_30, t21.password_requested_at AS
> password_requested_at_31, t21.roles AS roles_32, t21.id AS id_33,
> t21.nom AS nom_34, t21.prenom AS prenom_35, t21.telephone AS
> telephone_36, t21.fax AS fax_37, t21.is_active AS is_active_38,
> t21.date_first_login AS date_first_login_39, t21.role AS role_40,
> t21.portable_pro AS portable_pro_41, t21.utilisateur_id AS
> utilisateur_id_42, t21.agence_id AS agence_id_43,
> t0.utilisateur_id AS utilisateur_id_45, t0.agence_id AS
> agence_id_46 FROM employe t0 LEFT JOIN employe t21 ON
> t21.utilisateur_id = t44.id':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't44.id' in 'on
> clause'

Any idea about how to fix it ?

Comment: [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by this ? Can you tell me more ?

Answer (score 1):

Your changes to entity leaded to changes in table structure. Doctrine in your application works now with updated metadata and thinks that database has one structure but your database wasn't updated automatically and has another structure.

To synchronise database structure you need:

1. Generate migration (diff) for your database running script:

   ```
   php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
   ```
2. Run this migration:

   ```
   php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
   ```

Comment: I've tried doing this no changes so nothing to mograte :/

Comment: Did you run `doctrine:migrations:diff`? What is output of it? Do you still have the same problem that described in your post?